# vb.net equivalent to "private void (string text)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This might seem real simple but I am I'm building a website with help online but the code is in c#. I'm wondering what the equivalent vb code is? I'm looking for something along the lines of:  **"Private sub checkNo(string text)"** but its giving me errors. Many thanks in advance.

```
Private void checkNo(string text)

{

}
```

Comment: Did you try to research the errors? Did you read [ask]? Why not include your research and the actual error in your question?

Comment: [private (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

VB.NET uses `Sub` for `void` returning functions:

```
Private Sub checkNo(text as String)
End Sub
```

For future reference, if you've inherited a VB.NET code base, an [online converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) will generally handle the basics of C# to VB.NET conversion pretty well.